# T-SQL CASE multiple Conditions same Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i need in SQL the equivalent C# code for

```
int caseSwitch = 1;
switch (caseSwitch)
{
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
    Console.WriteLine("x");
    break;
default:
    Console.WriteLine("Default case");
    break;
}
```

i have multiple conditions and same result
and i don't want to write all code

```
case when cond1 then result1
     when cond2 then result1
     when cond3 then result1
     ....
     end
```

any ideas ?
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @caseSwitch INT=1
SELECT
    CASE WHEN @caseSwitch IN (1,2,3,4)
    THEN 'x'
    ELSE 'Default case'
END
```

In a table select. It would be something like this:

```
DECLARE @caseSwich INT=1
SELECT
    (
       CASE WHEN @caseSwich IN (1,2,3,4)
          THEN 'x'
          ELSE 'Default case'
       END
    ) AS someColumn
FROM
    yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 2
SELECT CASE WHEN @i IN (1,2,3,4) THEN 'Hi' ELSE 'HiHi' END AS Result
```

Answer (score 1):

If the set of values are small and stable then use a `CASE` expression, otherwise put the values in a lookup table e.g.

```
SELECT T.*, L.lookup_value AS result
  FROM T JOIN LookupTable ON T.lookup_key = L.lookup_key
UNION
SELECT T.*, 'Default case' AS result
  FROM T
 WHERE lookup_key NOT IN ( SELECT lookup_key FROM LookupTable );
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't get your idea

Comment: @Zyku: in the answer you accepted, the set (loosely speaking) of values `(1,2,3,4)` is hard coded into the query. If a second query needed to use the same set of values then you could copy+paste. When the set of values need to change, the maintenance guy (not necessarily you) will have to hunt down each occurrence of the set `(4,3,2,1)` (sets have no order!) and alter them. Now consider that SQL has but one data structure: the table. Sets of data are best modelled as tables e.g. makes their values and the code that uses them easier to maintain. But can be overkill for small and stable sets.

Comment: i understand your point but this is not the case, i need some simple values :  CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'nchar')
   CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar')
   CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'xml'
   CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('bigint', 'decimal', 'float', 'int', 'money', 'numeric', 'real', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 'tinyint')
   CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'uniqueidentifier'
   CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'smalldatetime', 'datetimeoffset')
   CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'bit'
                 CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'varbinary'

Comment: @Zyku: I agree those sets are small but are they stable? e.g. will you need to support geography spatial data type? new data types in a future version? etc. Anyhow, you get my idea so I wish you the best :)

Comment: thanks you too , yes I have 'geography' 'geometry' 'hierarchyid' types , but there were too many chars in comment